# @Database Export error in mySql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have databases in my MySQL Workbench, but when I try to export the database, it gives me errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error appears related to a [known limitation in Workbench 6.3.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-5.html). An upgrade to 6.3.6 should fix it. It's related to the bundled 5.7 mysqldump binary.